# Domains and trademarks - is there some legal risk

Tags: domains, legal, name, trademark

Suppose there is a trademark called "Rubyblock" and you buy rubyblock.com and name your app "Rubyblock" is there some legal risk?

If yes, how do i can check this before to name the app and buy domain?

Comment: This isn't a webmaster question, it's a legal question. That said, trademarks, servicemarks, & cet, are managed by the US Patent and Trademark Office. Go to http://www.uspto.gov to do a TESS search.

Comment: @psoft well can't this be usefull for a webmaster community to know?

Comment: I didn't vote to close. And I am not a lawyer.

Comment: @HugeNut It really depends on which country the trademark is in, and how it's being used. See these questions: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/50214/can-i-register-a-domain-name-that-contains-a-company-name-or-trademark and  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/53455/can-i-use-the-words-python-ruby-or-perl-in-a-domain-name